# wp_query with parameters

Tags: wp-query

I have a custom search page via which I select:

```
One or ALL categories
One or ALL tags
One or ALL authors
A search string or no search string
```

On the results page, wp_query works when I have selected values.
But how do I instruct to set some param as ALL? How do I set "search ALL categories" for example?

Maybe I need to break my args and add to them only when I got values? But how would I do that?

Thanks.

## EDIT

I modified the wp-query and now stands as follows. All works great but I do not have paging!

```
$args = array( 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date',  'posts_per_page'=> 10 ); 
if ( '0' != $category ) { $args['cat'] = $category; } 
if ( '0' != $tag ) { $args['tag'] = $tag; } 
if ( '0' != $author ) { $args['author'] = $author; } 
if ( '' != $search ) { $args['s'] = $search; } 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($the_query-> have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
....
endwhile;
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query ) );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have variables to hold your custom values for each:

- `$category`
- `$tag`
- `$author`
- `$search`

Then just create an arguments array, and add keys to it conditionally:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    // Set any default args here 
    // NOTE: This is where you'd add
    // things like pagination (posts_per_page),
    // order/sort parameters, and the like
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

// If user defines $category, add it
if ( '' != $category ) {
    $custom_query_args['cat'] = $category;
}
// If user defines $tag, add it
if ( '' != $tag ) {
    $custom_query_args['tag'] = $tag;
}

// If user defines $author, add it
if ( '' != $author ) {
    $custom_query_args['author'] = $author;
}

// If user defines $search, add it
if ( '' != $search ) {
    $custom_query_args['s'] = $search;
}

// Run the query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );
```

Note: how you define `$category`, `$tag`, `$author`, and `$search` is outside the scope of this answer.

#### Edit

If you want to [include a meta query (i.e. custom field) parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), you can do that as well:

Assuming (user-defined) `$post_meta_key` and (static) `$post_meta_key`:

```
// If user defines $post_meta_value, add it
if ( '' != $post_meta_value ) {
    $custom_query_args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => $post_meta_key,
            'value' => $post_meta_value,
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: This is very practical and very precise, many thanks.
Could I extend this question as per how to optionally narrow my search on a specific custom field? I know I could add this to the args[] as well but how?

Comment: I followed your code, it all works OK but I get max 10 results and never any paging. SOmethings missing?
$args = array(                   
 'order' => 'DESC',                                       
 'orderby' => 'date'
);

// If user defines $category, add it
if ( '0' != $category ) {
    $args['cat'] = $category;
}
// If user defines $tag, add it
if ( '0' != $tag ) {
    $args['tag'] = $tag;
}

// If user defines $author, add it
if ( '0' != $author ) {
    $args['author'] = $author;
}

if ( '' != $search ) {
    $args['s'] = $search;
}

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: I'll be happy to add that to the answer, but please **edit the question** to include the new information. Thanks :)

Comment: I updated the answer with an example meta query. For pagination, that's a completely separate issue, that has been asked several times. [See if any of these questions/answers are helpful](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+query+pagination).

Comment: Many thanks for your thorough feedback. One last question regarding search and custom fields: If I include $search and $meta_key1 and $meta_key2 in the wp_query, are they all considered as AND criteria? I.e. they must all be satisfied for a post to be returned?

Comment: Search and meta queries: yes. But multiple meta queries: not necessarily. In your array-of-arrays, you can define the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Chip! Another question: can this meta_query be LIKE and case sensitive?

Comment: Yes, the [meta query `'compare'` value](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) can be `'LIKE'`. I'm not sure if it is case-sensitive or not.